# Black and white (greyish color) console and X11

Tags: xorg, x11, gentoo

Can I achieve simply the state of my system with no color?
I'm using openbox.

Comment: Please explain that in more detail, it is not clear at all. Also telling us about what you've tried so far and why that didn't meet your need would make for better answers.

Comment: I don't know how to approach this question. What's the conception of this category? It might be driver, so I made search "nouveau monochrome driver" - no result. Then was a guess about GRUB parameter to the kernel, since it starts all the stuff - none. Then i figured about like it was in old DoS times, in Norton Commander with LCD panel, also there might be half-measures with --no-color parameters (in some of the portage packages) and customizations with X11. But the former ones are only half measures. I want to do all in one go.

Comment: Step 1 is this: explain what you're trying to do _in your question_. Even with that comment that's ~10 times longer than the body of your post, I'm still not sure I understand your _goal_. Please update your question (use the edit link right below the tags) to explain what you want to achieve, list what you've already tried, and explain why these things are not optimal/sufficient/nice.

Answer (score 2):

With Xorg, you can set the color `Depth` to 8 bits and `Visual` to "StaticGray" (see the xorg.conf manual page). That works, however I find that `iceweasel` at least is extremely slow to render.